# Select the rows where the column value have only numbers in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to select the rows where column1 will have only number value.

```
B07320CFT64100
B07320CFT64060
B07320RFX64100
00001512700990
00001512701003
00001512701355
00001512701355
```

Output:

```
00001512700990
00001512701003
00001512701355
00001512701355
```

Comment: If you are using Impala, why have you also tagged SQL Server & Hive?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_1 FROM Table where cast(column_1 as double) is not null;

Comment: I am using impala here and while i used this query it still returning rows which have alphabets.

Comment: Try using SELECT column_1 FROM Table where column_1 LIKE '[0-9]*';

Comment: SELECT column_1 FROM Table where cast(column_1 as double) is not null

Comment: this works for me.. i also  have another scenario some of the values in the column are like '00','000','0000000' and so on.how can i exclude  them.

Comment: you can try using ' regexp_like '. SELECT * FROM Table where not ( regexp_like(column_2, '0*');

Answer (score 0):

For all digits, you want:

```
where column_1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Or:

```
where column_1 REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'
```

Comment: @user11894930 "didn't work" is not a helpful comment.  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected results?  Impala definitely supports the `regexp` operator:  https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_operators.html#regexp.